# How to pause/resume the free forever M0 cluster in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am in the progress of learning MongoDB. Recently I created MongoDB Atlas cluser M0 (free) and I am unable to pause/ stop the service, I could see only the terminate option.

Will it automatically pause and resume based on activity? In that case, do we get any billing for having those clusters?

If we can pause manually, please provide the steps:

Comment: It will be automatically closed after a certain time of inactivity. You will not get any bill.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/pause-terminate-cluster/#m0-clusters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pause/resume option for the Mongo DB M0 Cluster type. It would automatically be disabled by the MongoDB after 60 days of no usage. Please find the same response from MongoDB team in [MongoDB Team answer in their Community webpage](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/stop-start-mongo-db-cluster-of-tier-m0-sandbox-through-atlas/235931)